# dc.js: How to change the data distribution in pie chart using different input threshold?

Tags: javascript, pie-chart, dc.js

I would like to use the score from input field to change the data distribution in pie chart.

For example, the distribution "71% High/ 28% Low" with scoreThreshold 0.5 will be changed to "42% High/ 57% Low" with scoreThreshold 0.7.

I made this example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/woodlan/6djxwqwc/2/), but the result was not satisfactory: when typing 0.5 in the input field and clicking "check!", the pie chart distribution does not change.

This decides the distribution:

```
//##  pie chart
var coreCount = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    var maxNumber=80;
    if (typeof scoreThreshold!='number') {scoreThreshold=0.5}
    //console.log(scoreThreshold)
    if (d.scores >maxNumber*scoreThreshold)
        {return 'High';}
    else {return 'Low';}
    });
```

I would like to renew the  coreCount function to reassign the distribution using input score threshold. But it does not work:

```
$('#scoreThresholdBt').click(function () { 
            scoreThreshold=document.getElementById('scoreThreshold').value
            scoreThreshold=parseFloat(scoreThreshold);
            console.log(scoreThreshold,typeof scoreThreshold);
            function redo_coreCount () {
                var coreCount = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
                    var maxNumber=80;
                    console.log(scoreThreshold);
                    if (d.count >maxNumber*scoreThreshold)
                        {return 'High';}
                    else {return 'Low';}
                    });
            }; redo_coreCount();
            coreCount.group();/**/
            dc.renderAll();
            dc.redrawAll();
        });
```

How can I realize this function?
I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are essentially putting the new dimension in a temporary variable which gets thrown away immediately. `coreCount` in the click function is unrelated to the variable with the same name at the global level.

Likewise, `coreCount.group()` is not an action; it's constructing a group object which will also get lost if you don't use it.

You need to assign the new dimension and group to your chart, since it doesn't track the value of the global or the local `coreCount`.

So let's change the function to return a new dimension based on reading the score threshold from the input:

```
function coreCount_from_threshold() {
  var scoreThreshold=document.getElementById('scoreThreshold').value;
  scoreThreshold=parseFloat(scoreThreshold);
  console.log(scoreThreshold,typeof scoreThreshold);
  if (isNaN(scoreThreshold)) {scoreThreshold=0.5}
  return ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    var maxNumber=80;
    if (d.scores >maxNumber*scoreThreshold)
        {return 'High';}
    else {return 'Low';}
    });
}
```

Note that we need to use `isNaN` here, because `typeof NaN === 'number'`

We can use this both at initialization time:

```
var coreCount = coreCount_from_threshold();
```

and on click:

```
$('#scoreThresholdBt').click(function () { 
    coreCount.dispose();
    coreCount = coreCount_from_threshold();
    coreCountGroup = coreCount.group();
    coreYesNoPieChart
      .dimension(coreCount)
      .group(coreCountGroup);
    dc.redrawAll();
});
```

Note that we are assigning to the same global variables `coreCount` and `coreCountGroup` (because we don't use `var` here). We first dispose the old dimension, because otherwise it would continue to filter and take up resources. Then we assign the new dimension and group to the chart (because otherwise it won't know about them).

We only need to do a redraw (not a render) here, because dc.js charts can just update when they get new data.

Here is a working [fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wg10nfkc/7/).

Comment: I tried this in your fiddle and noticed a few other problems, like having to dispose of the old dimension. I'll give it another shot on Monday.

Comment: Thank you very much,  Gordon, I tried your suggestion,  but there were still problems.  I am looking forward reading your feedback on Monday.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer with a few more necessary details. Would you consider contributing this example to dc.js? It would be nice to have an example of replacing the dimension & group.

Comment: Sure, Gordon. I have also another big project using dc.js, may I send the link to you via mail?

Comment: @Woodran, thanks for the PR. I will merge it soon. If anyone is looking for a complete example, it's here: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/1166